# Youtube API Android Project package not found error

Tags: android-youtube-api

I'm trying to incorporate the youtube player in an android app that i'm developing. But when I try to run the app it sais that the google api packages don't exist. In the code I don't have a single error. Its just when I try to install it on an android device that it doesn't install. I imported everything like in the youtube developers website says...

Can anyone help me?

Thank You

Comment: Could you please post more details? e.g., screenshots, log messages, project structure, build.gradle files..

Comment: I don't have enougth reputation to upload an image. But the error is this one: "error: package com.google.android.youtube.player does not exist". And this happens to every package that i use... I already added the sample code of the youtube api to the classpath... só I dont know what is happening...